# Execute a sql script for all the tables to run in parallel in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an index rebuild and reorganize script to alter rebuild or alter reorganize based on fragmentation in SQL Server.

At present we are running that script in SSIS package for all the tables to alter indexes that are necessary to rebuild or reorganize in sequential manner

For example, consider There are 2 tables

Table 1 has index1, index2
Table 2 has index1, index2, index3

That script starts altering
table1 -index1, table1 - index2 then starts altering table 2-index1. This process is taking a long time

Now we want to executing script for all tables in parallel

Something like this
Table1 - index1, table2- index1 and so on
The indexes in table should be executed in sequential but the script should start executing for all tables in parallel

Is this possible to do in SSIS package?

Comment: Do you actually need to do it though? https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sequence container for each table and execute each sequence container separately like below:

[image]